# Загрузка изображений с Firebase storage в ImageView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-android

Как я могу загружать изображения из Firebase storage в `ImageView`? Я нашел такой код для скачивания изображения на устройство, но еще не до конца понимаю, что именно здесь происходит:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference rootRef = storage.getReference();
islandRef = rootRef.child("images/island.jpg");

File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");

rootRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Как я могу используя этот код загружать полученное изображение в `ImageView`. Есть ли альтернативные способы получения изображений из Firebase storage в `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Код асинхронно пытается загрузить файл и записать в `localFile`.
2. После окончания загрузки сработает либо `onFailure` в случае проблем, либо `onSuccess` при успехе.
3. При вызове `onSuccess` файл уже сохранён в `localFile` и теперь можно это картинку установить в `ImageView`.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!